# Creating irregular shaped buttons

Tags: android, button

I need to create `buttons` as shown in the image below

3 buttons of different shapes aligned side by side

[image: 3 buttons of different shapes aligned side by side]

The entire area on the button should be clickable, but I don't know if it can be done in android.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Use Photoshop and Image Button**

Making the images in Photoshop and then import them in Android Studio and apply them using image button widget.

**Use a Custom Layout**

Make a custom layout in XML format and them use that as that as view for buttons

Comment: Creating view is not an issue, Handling the touch event is the main concern. Here buttons are not square. To design view like above, the images will be rectangular in shape with transparent background. In this case The transparent area of one button will be on top of other button, cannot handle click event properly on each button.